# How to calculate Max value using Map-Reduce in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I know there's the built-in `_stats` function that gives you sum, count, min, max, and sumsqr. 
What I'd like to know is how to calculate just the max in a map-reduce way. I can't come up with a reduce function that will work without some more information.

The only thing I can think of is to use sorting on the value and pick off the first value.

My map function looks like this:

```
function(doc){
  emit(null, doc.value);
}
```

Comment: Your workaround (sorting by value and picking the first or last entry) will not work with your map function - a view is sorted by key, so you would need to emit doc.value instead of null as a key. But instead of such workaround you can combine the map function you have with an appropriate reduce function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The couchdb wiki provides a simple [example for sum](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions).

Instead of returning the sum of values, a reduce function for max should return the max of the values array. Since calculating the maximum is commutative, associative etc. you do not need to worry about rereduce.

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    // Return the maximum numeric value.
    var max = -Infinity
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        if(typeof values[i] == 'number')
            max = Math.max(values[i], max)
    return max
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of expanding your answer to include what I am pretty sure will solve PPC-Coder's problem.

Comment: Is there a similar way to find max date for a set of rows?

Answer (score 12):

This may be also solved by the following

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
  return Math.max.apply({}, values);
}
```