# How to select record with max value?

Tags: javascript, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have the following view :

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (meta.type == "json")
  if ( doc.id 
      && doc.id.root.indexOf("1.2.250.1.199.16.1.1") == 0 
      && doc.setId
      && doc.versionNumber)
  {
    emit(doc.setId.extension, parseInt(doc.versionNumber.value))
  }
}
```

That returns the following result set :

```
Key Value
"4816f76e-33f9-456a-9e23-961799883994" 1
wound2QualificationRev1

"4816f76e-33f9-456a-9e23-961799883994" 2
wound2QualificationRev2
```

Now I would like to restrict the result set on the max value to return only

```
Key Value
"4816f76e-33f9-456a-9e23-961799883994" 2
wound2QualificationRev2
```

How would I modify the view ? With a custom reduce method ?

**EDIT 1** : Please note that the result set shown here is partial. I can't use orderby and limit to achieve my goal.

Comment: please supply some data/structure and the function emit()

Comment: @NinaScholz Well "emit()" is a Couchbase internal function. Did you see the question was related to Couchbase ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Couchbase, but what about writing something like :

```
 emit(parseInt(doc.versionNumber.value),doc.setId.extension)
```

then querying it with :

```
?descending=true&&limit=1
```

You can also use a map reduce : [How to calculate Max value using Map-Reduce in CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107693/how-to-calculate-max-value-using-map-reduce-in-couchdb?lq=1), or considerate the usage of N1QL, which implements MIN and MAX SQL queries

Comment: That would have been a solution until my first edit of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit. Then what about using a reduce : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107693/how-to-calculate-max-value-using-map-reduce-in-couchdb) ? Other way should be the usage of N1QL, which implements MIN and MAX SQL queries.

Comment: using a reduce is part of the solution. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well **Kudos** to @Leogiciel for the Max reduce function, I finally found the solution.
First, the view definition is left unchanged.
The solution is to use this implementation of the [Max reduce function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107693/how-to-calculate-max-value-using-map-reduce-in-couchdb?lq=1) and, most importantly, **group and reduce** with query parameters.

The initial result set, shown here as raw Json:

```
{"total_rows":9,"rows":[
{"id":"wound1Image1","key":"0a41d087-1a7f-4d9f-8df9-83d0deb2566c","value":1},
{"id":"wound2QualificationRev1","key":"4816f76e-33f9-456a-9e23-961799883994","value":1},
{"id":"wound2QualificationRev2","key":"4816f76e-33f9-456a-9e23-961799883994","value":2},
{"id":"wound2Image3","key":"65ff979a-e1e0-43d4-a24f-a3ee0cc8b67c","value":1},
{"id":"wound2Image1","key":"69f29cf8-3ee7-4681-937d-d465edc9bb16","value":1},
{"id":"wound1Image2","key":"76ab9a67-a17b-4fc6-a105-60b57e971d4f","value":1},
{"id":"wound1Synthesis","key":"bc1a7ec0-30d7-4493-8dd9-dcf6d0b48cc9","value":1},
{"id":"wound1Qualification","key":"cb375a5f-e07d-449a-ab13-60dba16a0323","value":1},
{"id":"wound2Image2","key":"dfb5e7eb-6192-46ba-84d2-0e5996536930","value":1}
]
}
```

with the following query parameters:

```
?group=true&reduce=true
```

returns the correct result set:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"0a41d087-1a7f-4d9f-8df9-83d0deb2566c","value":1},
{"key":"4816f76e-33f9-456a-9e23-961799883994","value":2},
{"key":"65ff979a-e1e0-43d4-a24f-a3ee0cc8b67c","value":1},
{"key":"69f29cf8-3ee7-4681-937d-d465edc9bb16","value":1},
{"key":"76ab9a67-a17b-4fc6-a105-60b57e971d4f","value":1},
{"key":"bc1a7ec0-30d7-4493-8dd9-dcf6d0b48cc9","value":1},

{"key":"cb375a5f-e07d-449a-ab13-60dba16a0323","value":1},    {"key":"dfb5e7eb-6192-46ba-84d2-0e5996536930","value":1}
]
}
```